# Updating Clojure version for Clooj IDE

Tags: clojure, ide

I'm using a Clojure IDE called Clooj and it's using the 1.5 version of Clojure while I want to use the most recent version, 1.8.

It has a GitHub page and comes as a JAR. It doesn't have any button for updating the Clojure version. How am I updating it considering I'm a beginner in programming. I'm very decided to use this IDE.

Should I unpack the JAR?
Or to take the GitHub files, change one file and then pack them somehow?

Comment: So you are very decided to use an IDE that hasn't been updated in over 2 years and that basically no other Clojure developers use? Why exactly?

Comment: I tried Nightcode and it has alot of bugs. I change the original file, run it and it still sais "Hello World" although I wrote a different code. The save button doesn't work. The files are compiling to slow, it takes ages. It also gives me compile errors although I copy-pasted the code from a tutorial and it's identical. It also doesn't have "copy" "paste" submenus if I press rightclick which is a shame for a modern program.

Comment: Well, Nightcode is another IDE that's not exactly widely used. Most Clojure developers I know use Emacs, and quite a lot of people seem to be happy with IntelliJ+Cursive.

Comment: Did you try the current NightCode (2.1.6)? Though it lacks a pop-up edit menu, I have not found the other faults you report. But ...  [Parinfer](https://shaunlebron.github.io/parinfer/) can silently change the structure of pasted code; and Copy->pasting from web-pages doesn't work (on Linux).

Comment: Cursive asks me for an SDK and I have no clue what an SDK is.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be abandonware (& not really complete from the
    beginning).  You're probably better off using Vim, Emacs, IntelliJ
    IDEA/Cursive (my favorite for Clojure), NightCode, or another
    choice.

If you want to play around with this code, just clone the project
    and look at `project.clj`.

Change the clojure version from

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
```

to

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
```

Comment: And after I do that, how do I pack it back as a functioning JAR?

Comment: It deosn't recognize the JAR file, it said "Invalid or corrupt jarfile".